# How can I do a migration on codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the migration codes which works on CodeIgniter 2 but they won't work on CodeIgniter 3

I have read most of the questions here similar to my problem but I could not find an answer.

........

```
class Migration_Create_users extends CI_Migration
{
   public function up()
   {
       $this->dbforge->add_field([
           'id'       => [
               'type'           => 'INT',
               'constraint'     => 11,
               'unsigned'       => true,
               'auto_increment' => true,
           ],
           'email'    => [
               'type'       => 'VARCHAR',
               'constraint' => '100',
           ],
           'password' => [
               'type'       => 'VARCHAR',
               'constraint' => '128',
           ],
           'name'     => [
               'type'       => 'VARCHAR',
               'constraint' => '100',
           ],
       ]);
       $this->dbforge->add_key('id', true);
       $this->dbforge->create_table('users');
   }
   public function down()
   {
       $this->dbforge->drop_table('users');
   }
}
```

```
class Migration extends Admin_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('migration');
        if (!$this->migration->current()) {
            show_error($this->migration->error_string());
        } else {
            echo 'Migration worked!';
        }
    }
}
```

//migration config

```
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['migration_enabled']     = true;
$config['migration_type']        = 'sequential';
$config['migration_table']       = 'migrations';
$config['migration_auto_latest'] = false;
$config['migration_version']     = 001;
$config['migration_path']        = APPPATH . 'migrations/';
```

I expect to run the code then I get the table created in the database

Comment: Please reformat the code.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so next time you can reformat your own code

Answer (score 0):

Please do with the below function

```
class Migrate extends CI_Controller{

    public function index($version){
        $this->load->library("migration");

      if(!$this->migration->version($version)){
          show_error($this->migration->error_string());
      }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply Justin but still it is not working. I still get the same error!